# Showing values in commas on JTable

Tags: java, swing

I have added a `JTable` on the panel in Netbeans.

I have some text fields on the panel too, now I am trying to get all the data from text fields and put it on `JTable`. I have written the code and the data is showing, but it is not in the format of table: it is something like commas etc..

Please, could you tell me where I am making mistake and why it is not in the shape of table?

This is a snippet of code:

```
    Vector headings=new Vector();
    Vector rows=new Vector();

    headings.add("Item No");
    headings.add("Item Name");
    headings.add("Stock");
    headings.add("Quantity");
    headings.add("Purchase Price");
    headings.add("Unit");
    headings.add("Amount");

    DefaultTableModel dataModel=new DefaultTableModel();
    dataModel.addColumn(headings);

    Vector row=new Vector();

    row.add(this.itemIdTextField.getText());
    row.add(this.itemNameTextField.getText());
    row.add(this.stockTextField.getText());
    row.add(this.quantityTextField.getText());
    row.add(this.purchasePriceTextField.getText());
    row.add(this.unitTextField.getText());
    row.add(this.amountTextField.getText());

    rows.add(row);
    dataModel.addRow(rows);

    this.purchaseTable.setModel(dataModel);
```

[image: This image shows the output of this program]

Comment: 1) *"This is a snippet of code"* For better help sooner post a proper [mcve] 2) You're adding a single column containing the `headings` Vector. Why not create your `rows` Vector and your `headings`, then just call `dataModel = new DefaultTableModel(rows, headings)`? 3) Why use `Vector`? Why don't you use a `List` (`ArrayList`)? They're asynchronous while `Vector` is synchronous...

Comment: @Frakcool, `Why use Vector? Why don't you use a List ` - the DefaultTableModel uses Vectors. If you want to use a List then you need to create a custom TableModel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> could you tell me where I am making mistake and why it is not in the shape of table?

The `addRow(...)` method is used to add a single row of data to the model, not a Vector of Vectors.

So you don't need the "rows" Vector and the code should just be:

```
//rows.add(row);
//dataModel.addRow(rows);
dataModel.addRow( row );
```

And when you create the DefaultTableModel you should be using:

```
//DefaultTableModel dataModel=new DefaultTableModel();
DefaultTableModel dataModel=new DefaultTableModel(headings, 0);
```

Or if you really want to create a Vector of Vectors, then you need to create the column and data Vectors first and then create the JTable using:

```
JTable table = new JTable(rows, headings);
```

Or you can create the DefaultTableModel first:

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(rows, headings);
JTable table = new JTable( model );
```

Comment: could you please tell me that what is the meaning of passing headings, 0 in the constructor of DefaultTableModel ??

Comment: @TaimoorKhan, Did you read the API for the DefaultTableModel constructors? That is the first thing you should do, not only for this, but for the entire question. Then if there is something about the API description you don't understand you ask a question. You can't program if you don't read the API.

Comment: can you suggest me a book in which I can make expert myself ?

Comment: No I don't know of any book. You can start with the [Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html). The section on `Creating a GUI With Swing` might be a good place to start.